# blender + windows remote desktop

Tags: rendering, error

we recently bought a windows desktop for archviz modeling and rendering with Blender (AMD Epyc + 2xRTX2080Ti). The pc is placed in a server room and we want to remotely use it, on an iMac with two monitors, using Windows Remote desktop.

Now I discovered Blender doesn't work well in this setup. I managed to install the .bat-solution (auto disconnect, then launch blender remotely en reconnect to the pc). Of course this has a lot of disadvantages, certainly because the pc is not used for rendering only but also for modeling, compositing, etc.

I'm wondering if there's maybe a new solution to this? Or are there any plans to implement a solution into Blender? A lot of other 3d-software don't have this problem, so maybe it's quite easy to solve?

If not, anybody knows a different solution to remotely use the pc? Teamviewer or chrome remote desktop is no solution, it should be smooth enough to work on all day.

Thanks!
Thomas

Comment: Hi. Can you clarify what you mean by "Blender doesn't work well"? What happens vs what you want to happen. You can add any extra info by using the [edit] link below the question.

Comment: Windows remote desktop does not work for blender. It is a limitation on the RDP protocol and OpenGL. Use other alternatives like VNC or similar.